# Custom deleter specifications for std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, unique-ptr

I am reading Josuttis` C++ standard library.  I could not find the reasoning for the (2) and (3) comments on following example:

```
D d;  //instance of the deleter type(1)
unique_ptr<int,D> p1(new int, D()); //D must be  MoveConstructible(2)
unique_ptr<int,D> p2(new int, d);  //D must be CopyConstructible(3)
```

What are the reasons for comment (2) and (3) in this context?

What are the specifications for custom deleter for `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: Which part of this do you have trouble [finding documentation for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification is accurately described on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) (constructors #3-4), and comes directly from the C++ standard section [unique.ptr.single.ctor]. Since your `D` is a non-reference type, the signatures are as follows:

> ```
> unique_ptr(pointer p, const A& d);   // your (3)
> unique_ptr(pointer p, A&& d);        // your (2)
> ```

where `A` is a synonym for `D`. These constructors require:

> *Requires:*
>
> — If `D` is not an lvalue-reference type then
>
> - If `d` is an lvalue or `const` rvalue then the first constructor of this pair will be selected. `D` shall
>     satisfy the requirements of `CopyConstructible` (Table 21), and the copy constructor of `D`shall not throw an exception. This `unique_ptr` will hold a copy of `d`.
> - Otherwise, `d` is a non-`const` rvalue and the second constructor of this pair will be selected. `D`
>     shall satisfy the requirements of `MoveConstructible` (Table 20), and the move constructor
>     of `D` shall not throw an exception. This `unique_ptr` will hold a value move constructed from
>     `d`.

The first bullet point describes your case (3), the second describes your case (2).

Answer (score 3):

For case 2) you are using a temporary, so the compiler can move it.
On case 3) you are giving an object that cannot be moved, so the compiler will need to make a copy.